# Replace single in between values in using python in insert statement

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I am trying to push data from google sheet to database but getting error more columns than insert statement.

```
import vertica_python
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import gspread.utils
#from utils import gspread.utils.batch_clear
#utils.path.insert(0, 'C:\\\Python311\\\Lib\\\site-packages\\\gspread\\\')

# Set up Google Sheets API credentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('cred.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Connect to Vertica database
conn_info = {
    'host': 'host',
    'port': 5433,
    'user': 'user',
    'password': 'password',
    'database': 'db'
}
connection = vertica_python.connect(**conn_info)
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Specify Google Sheet details
spreadsheet_key = 'spreadsheet_ID'
worksheet_name = 'Sheet1'
print('open')
# Retrieve data from Google Sheet
sheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheet_key)
worksheet = sheet.worksheet(worksheet_name)
data = worksheet.get_all_values()
print('Close')
# Prepare and execute SQL statements to insert data into Vertica
columns = data[0]  # Assumes the first row contains column names
insert_statement = "INSERT INTO table ({}) VALUES ({})"
for row in data[1:]:  # Skip the first row (column names)
    values = "', '".join(row)  # Assumes values are strings
    insert_query = insert_statement.format(', '.join(columns), "'" + values + "'")
    # print(n +' '+insert_query)
    cursor.execute(insert_query)

# Commit changes and close connections
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Input: `insert into table(col1,col2,col2) values('Apple','Samsung's','nine')`

Samsung's is causing an issue, can we replace it to like Samsung''s in for loop in script?

Comment: I'm not sure what db you are using but  mySQL and PostgreSQL accept 'Samsung\'s' for example. or 'Samsung' + char(39) + 's'. 'Samsung''s' should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

seems like it, so you can escape the `'` in your code by replacing them with `''` :

```py
insert_statement = "INSERT INTO table ({}) VALUES ({})"
for row in data[1:]:  # Skip the first row (column names)
    values = "', '".join([item.replace("'", "''") for item in row]) # Assumes values are strings
    insert_query = insert_statement.format(', '.join(columns), "'" + values + "'")
    # print(n +' '+insert_query)
    cursor.execute(insert_query)
```

Comment: tried that, other values too gets replaced like 'Apple' --> ''Apple''

Comment: this worked values = "', '".join([item.replace("'", "''") for item in row])